# fallo en el menu full screen, los elementos del menu no desaparecen del la pagina principal

Tags: javascript, html, css

fallo en el menu full screen, los elementos del menu no desaparecen del la pagina principal
y necesito que se quite porque no puedo hacer la pagina con el menu delante de la pagina.
fallo en el menu full screen, los elementos del menu no desaparecen del la pagina principal
y necesito que se quite porque no puedo hacer la pagina con el menu delante de la pagina.

[image: fallo del menu]

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('container-menu');
var cerrar = document.getElementById('cerrar');
var item = document.getElementById('item');

function mostrar() {

    menu.style.padding = '26px 26px 200vw 200vw';
    cerrar.style.display = 'block';
    item.style.display = 'flex';
    
}

function ocultar() {

    menu.style.padding = '26px 26px 52px 52px';
    cerrar.style.display = 'none';
    item.style.display = 'none';

}

function blanco(){

    cerrar.style.display = 'none';
    item.style.display = 'none';

}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:sans-serif ;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container-menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background:linear-gradient(10deg,rgb(0, 225, 255), blue);
    border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 100%;
    padding: 26px 26px 52px 52px;
    transition: all 2s;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.icono-menu{
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.icon-close{
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 26px;

}
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;


}

.menu a{
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 34px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: whitesmoke;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

}



.menu a:before{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu a:hover:before{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="galeria2.css">
    <title>Invelux</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-menu" id="container-menu">
    <i class="fas fa-list-ul icono-menu" 
    onclick="mostrar()"></i>
</div>
<i class="fas fa-times icon-close" id="cerrar" onclick="ocultar()" ></i>

<div class="menu" id="item" >
    <a href="/invelux.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="#">Galeria</a>
    <a href="">Información</a>
    <a href="#">Contactos</a>

</div>


<script src="/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/378ba76060.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

fallo en el menu full screen, los elementos del menu no desaparecen del la pagina principal
y necesito que se quite porque no puedo hacer la pagina con el menu delante de la pagina.fallo en el menu full screen, los elementos del menu no desaparecen del la pagina principal
y necesito que se quite porque no puedo hacer la pagina con el menu delante de la pagina.

Comment: No veo el fallo al ejecutar el menú se expande y contrae correctamente. Sólo una observación: los dos comportamientos pueden lograrse con el "botón del menú hamburguesa" (toggle) de modo que el botón de cierre **(X)** sobra.

Comment: el fallo es cuando arrancas la pagina esta los en laces del menu en la pagina, hasta que no abres el menu y lo cierras no desaparece de la principal @quevedo

Comment: Entonces es simple en el evento onload puedes invocar el método cerrar o, asignar los estados correspondientes, como te resulte mejor

Comment: ya lo he intentado ponerle también un onload antes del onclick con la funcion de ocultar pero no funciona tampoco

Comment: `<body onload="ocultar();">`

Comment: muchísimas gracias @quevedo ya me funciona perfectamente:)

Comment: puedo preguntarte porque funciona con un abre y cierra body y no dentro del propio <i>?

Comment: Funciona porque el evento onload de la etiqueta body se produce una vez ha sido cargada la página completa. De modo que en ese momento toda la estructura está disponible. Mientras que el evento que declaras en el elemento i es onclick y va a estar disponible luego de que la página esté siendo mostrada.

Comment: aah vale ya entiendo, muchas gracias @quevedo